# Java byte array larger than jpg image

Tags: java, arrays, image, byte

I have a quite intriguing question, I am converting jpg image to byte array in Java, like this:

```
>   public byte[] toBytes(String file) throws IOException {
        File img = new File(file);
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(img);
        WritableRaster r = image.getRaster();
        DataBufferByte data = (DataBufferByte) r.getDataBuffer();

        return data.getData();
    }
```

This is obviously only a part of a system but please believe my word ^_^ : 
this method returns a byte array, however - when I give it a .jpg file of the size of some 20,000 bytes (Linux - right click on image -> properties -> size shown as around 20 000 bytes), obtained byte array has length of over 345 000, that is 345 000 bytes (all of them initialised to some values, not just 0-s). Do you guys know why is this happening?

Comment: If you're on linux and using a right click to check out the size of an image, then sorry buddy, but I won't _believe your word_.

Comment: Jpeg is compressed ... so .....

Comment: What is wrong with using a graphic interface on Linux?????????? Have you heard about - Ubuntu ?? It is operating System and obviously - it has graphic (quite nice actually) interface, like many other linux distros.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Jpeg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG) is a highly compressed graphic format. It uses various tricks to encode an image in as few bytes as possible without making it look too different from the original (at least as far as the human eye can tell).

However, when you rasterize an image with `image.getRaster()`, the image gets decoded. All the compression-tricks are reverted to create an uncompressed image with 3 byte per pixel (one for red, green and blue).

When you want the compressed JPEG data for some reason, access the `File` object directly with a [`FileInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html).

Comment: Thanks. That's what I have thought - but was not sure. Do you know any good source to learn about graphics formats?? Preferably online? In particular I mean things like headers, how to read them and so on.

Comment: By the way - if 1 pixel becomes 3 bytes, what about alpha channel?

Comment: @PawelHuszcza JPEG has no alpha channel.